# CodenameOne build login failed

Tags: codenameone

I can log into the web site, but the builds do not log in. I was able to build yesterday, but not today.  I'm getting the following build error:

"You have a build in progress within the queue. Only one build may be active at a time
/Users/admin/Documents/DevNetbeans/CodenameOneHiThere/build.xml:338: Login failed"

I've reset the password in the CodenameOne setting/login, but still no success.

Answer (score 2):

Log into the website dashboard an cancel any pending builds you have.  Then send another build.